# The effect of temperature on Coulomb's law

Tags: thermodynamics, electrostatics, temperature, coulombs-law, electrical-engineering

I have read a sentence in an electrical engineering article but I couldn't understand it.

It said: on Earth Temperatures around 150 million degrees Celsius are required to overcome Coulomb's law. the force between two charged particles, so that the fusion between Atoms can occur.

Why? Does temperature affect Coulomb's law?

Comment: Well, the temperature relates to average kinetic energy, and if that kinetic energy is high enough to overcome the coulomb barrier than you can get fusion. Or, with an ion accelerator you can give a specific kinetic energy and accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you for your Reply. But actually I don't understand why coulomb's force is an obstacle to fusion?

Answer (score 1):

For nuclei to fuse (stick together) they need to come close enough (within about 1 fm ($1 \times 10^{-15}$ m) of each other. But the nuclei, being positively charged, repel each other (Coulomb repulsion). If fast-moving nuclei approach each other they will lose kinetic energy (KE) because they have to do work against the Coulomb force. They may run out of KE, and start to move apart again (because of the repulsive force) before they get close enough to fuse. However, if they are moving fast enough, as will happen at very high temperatures, they can get within 1 fm of each other before they lose all their kinetic energy. Fusion is then possible.

So it's the kinetic energy of the nuclei that is temperature-dependent, not Coulomb's law itself.

Answer (score 0):

Nuclear fusion on earth is done with deuterium (a hydrogen isotope with one neutron) and tritium (a hydrogen isotope with two neutrons).  Both atoms contain one proton, which is positively charged.  Since like charges repel, there is a repulsive force between these two nuclei that is calculated with Coulomb's Law, and that rapidly increases in magnitude as the nuclei approach other.  If these two nuclei can be forced close enough together, the strong nuclear force will become stronger than the repulsive Coulomb force, the nuclei will fuse together, and a large amount of energy will be released as a result.  The standard way of forcing these nuclei to approach each other close enough for this to happen requires that the nuclei approach each other at very high velocities (high kinetic energies).  Increasing temperature increases the kinetic energy of the atoms, and if the temperature gets to approximately 150 million degrees C, the kinetic energy is high enough to force deuterium and tritium nuclei close enough to fuse.

Answer (score 0):

Temperature does not affect the Coulomb force- the force is entirely independent of temperature.

Fusion can only occur when protons are brought into very close contact. The Coulomb force is an obstacle to fusion because its effect is to keep protons apart.

The need for a high temperature is nothing to do with weakening the Coulomb force- it is to do with throwing the protons together at such a high speed that they are able to come into close contact notwithstanding the effect of the Coulomb force.